# How do I call the method in the sub-class in java?

Tags: java

I have some sub classes and one base.
Base is `movie`, and I would like to call the method in the `Fiction` method which is sub-class.
The method will be called from other method called (management.java).
Fiction has its own field called `typeOfmovie` and getter and setter method.
What I'm trying to do is, I would like to call that getter or setter method.
But even if I create like:

```
Movie m = new Fiction();
```

I cannot call getter or setter method from there.
The only way is I should create abstract method in the `movie` class?
I could, but as the number of fields getting bigger, I thought the base class might get messy.

Is that only way I can do?

Also, the field is package private (default), but I still cannot access that way either
Can you give me an advice please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Declaration say's m is of type movie , so it can call methods that are declared in Movie only ( if any of base class methods overridden in your subclass, then overridden method code will be executed ). But if You want to call extra methods in subclass .You have to create your object like this

> Fiction f = new Fiction();

Comment: What is the difference between Fiction f = new Fiction();  and 
Movie f = new Fiction()  ? May I ask?

Comment: Fiction f - > f is an object of type f , Movie f - > f is an object of type M . Think in compiler point of view You typed Movie m = new Fiction(); at this point compiler only knows m is of type Movie , no object created yet ( only at run time it creates objects) , so if you try to access method that doesn't exist in class Movie it don't allow . That being said i am not saying after created an object m can access Fiction methods because m is object of Type movie . Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your two options are to put the method on `Movie` -- which has the drawback you mention -- or to cast `m` down to `Fiction`:

```
Fiction f = (Fiction) m;
f.typeOfMovie();
```

But often (not always), needing to do that downcast suggests that your code isn't organized in the most object-oriented-esq of ways. It's hard to know if that's the case without context.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use members of the derived class, you should declare the field as an instance of the derived class.